# Double Spirit Shroud with Death Domain

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, concentration

The ability from the Death Domain Cleric is *Improved Reaper*:

> Starting at 17th level, when you cast a necromancy spell of 1st through 5th level that targets only one creature, the spell can instead target two creatures within range and within 5 feet of each other. If the spell consumes its material components, you must provide them for each target.

Nowhere in the ability does it state that spells with a range of 'Self' are excluded. This differs from the Sorcerer's metamagic *Twinned Spell*:

> Twinned Spell. When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and **doesn't have a range of self**, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell's level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip). To be eligible for Twinned Spell, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell's current level.

Assuming that the caster is within 5 feet of an ally, could *Improved Reaper*  be used to cast two *Spirit Shroud* spells with only one person concentrating?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Another creature cannot be within range “self”.

*Spirit shroud* states:

> the spell can instead target two creatures *within range*

Improved Reaper doesn’t specify what “within range” is within the text of the feature, so it has to be referring to the range of the spell you cast. Since *spirit shroud* has a range of self, and Improved Reaper requires that the second creature be “within range”, you cannot target a second creature, since you are the only creature within range “self”.

Comment: Dare we ask about the edge case involving a find steed provided from a ring of spell storing?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I don't think there's any difficulty in that corner case. Both the Improved Reaper domain feature and the relevant clause of Find Steed let you add an additional target to a spell you are casting. But since both of them require you to have only one target before they apply, you can't ever combine the two effects, since after the first rule is applied, the spell will have two targets.